# Filter list elements in a Series of lists by a series of boolean masks

Tags: python, pandas, filter, boolean, series

I have a two Series which are like the following:
Series 1 has str list whereas Series 2 numpy array with Boolean expressions in it.

But I have like 50,000 rows in them and I want to see values based on the Boolean expression like

```
ser1 = pd.Series([[1, 2, 3], [4], [7, 8]])
ser2 = pd.Series([[True, False, True], [False], [True, True]])

ser1

0    [1, 2, 3]
1          [4]
2       [7, 8]
dtype: object

ser2

0    [True, False, True]
1                [False]
2           [True, True]
dtype: object
```

And,

```
Output=[1,3],[],[7,8],....
```

I tried two methods but cannot construct them properly, the first one gets too much time where the second one is not working.

```
output=[]
for i in range(len(Series1)):
output.append(Series1.apply(np.array)[i][Series2[i]])

output=[Series1.apply(lambda x: x[i]) for i in Series2]
```

Do you have any suggestion that I can obtain this output?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ser1 = pd.Series([[1, 2, 3], [4], [7, 8]])
ser2 = pd.Series([[True, False, True], [False], [True, True]])
```

There are a couple of ways to do it, but I would not recommend `apply`. One option is to `zip` the series and filter using numpy's boolean indexing:

```
pd.Series([np.array(x)[y] for x, y in zip(ser1, ser2)])

0    [1, 3]
1        []
2    [7, 8]
dtype: object
```

If you need the result as a list, call `.tolist` at the end:

```
output = pd.Series([list(np.array(x)[y]) for x, y in zip(ser1, ser2)]).tolist()
output
# [[1, 3], [], [7, 8]]
```

---

You can also make this a pure python list comp with a nested list comprehension.

```
pd.Series([
    [i for i, j in zip(x, y) if j] for x, y in zip(ser1, ser2)])

0    [1, 3]
1        []
2    [7, 8]
dtype: object
```

I recommend this *FOR SMALL LISTS* because converting lists to numpy arrays (as done the first solution) incurs significant overhead.

---

If flattening your lists is an option, you should consider doing so, because this would likely be the fastest option.

```
from itertools import chain

ser3 = np.array(list(chain.from_iterable(ser1)))
ser4 = np.array(list(chain.from_iterable(ser2)))

ser3[ser4]
# array([1, 3, 7, 8])
```

Unfortunately, you lose the structure of your input, but if that isn't a problem, this is a winner.

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine when I used zip function. List comprehension is taking too much time due to my huge data.

Comment: @AltuğKamacıoğlu The first option with numpy is worth it if the arrays are large. As an alternative, you should consider flattening your data.